# Adding a tag in KML file Using R

Tags: html, r, xml, kml

I've kml file exported from Google Earth Pro, consist of 37 Folder, each Folder contain number of "minor" Folder, the number of total "minor" Folders is 168, each "minor" has 3 placemarks.

I've HTML code, i made it with R, and want to import this kml file into R and put this HTML code into the first "Placemark" for each "minor" Folder, this HTML code isn't constant,  it has variables like the values in the table in this code, and this variables will attached from dataframe i made for this "minor" Folder,when i edit this HTML code, i'll put it into the first "placemark" for this "minor" Folder, and so on for the other "minor" Folders.

is there any fuction in R that can add this html code to the kml file ?

here's the code of "description" in R.

```
URL <- paste("file:///C:/Users/pc/Downloads/Googletraffic/Tazbet/Autostrad;Helwan To Da2ery/",FileName,sep = "")
library(XML)

top = newXMLNode("description")

table = newXMLNode("table ", attrs = c(width = 300, border = 1), parent = top)
tbody <- newXMLNode("tbody",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(Bey2ollak$V3),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(Bey2ollak$V3),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(Bey2ollak$V3),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)

th <- newXMLNode("img",attrs = c(src = URL,width = "700",height= "777",alt=""),parent =top )



top
```

here's the output in console

```
<description>
  <table  width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">5</th>
      <th scope="col">MD</th>
      <th scope="col">PM</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">5</th>
      <th scope="col">MD</th>
      <th scope="col">PM</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">5</th>
      <th scope="col">MD</th>
      <th scope="col">PM</th>
    </tr>
  </table >
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/pc/Downloads/Googletraffic/Tazbet/Autostrad;Helwan To Da2ery/Spiral.jpg " width="700" height="777" alt=""/>
</description>
```

[here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2lPFjKRVKWWmdxc2dTcGpkdzQ) my kml file

Comment: The `XML` package enables adding, removing and editing tags, tag attributes and tag values.

Comment: The XML library may be what you want. See this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505906/use-r-to-read-a-xml-file-select-few-nodes-and-write-it-back-to-another-xml

Comment: @hrbrmstr, i'm reading the manual , i'm looking for a function that add a tag in a specific place, please if you find an answer, help me .

Comment: @JMT_2080AD, that's not what i'm searching for, it creates but not adding.

Comment: http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/XML/html/append.XMLNode.html

Comment: @JMT_2080AD, is there any way to make R read my code for description ? instead of writing the code from begging on R ? i tried the site u sent, it was useful but i'm not familiar with xml and html so i was writting what i want on Dream Weaver then get that code

Comment: or i should write it better to edit it when i want ?

Comment: @Alsqer If you want to parse KML you need to learn about the DOM. It's not that hard to pick up the basics. It will be time well spent. If I have time later I will see if I can write up an R script for you. I will be a good learning experience for me too. I've been working with more XML type documents lately.

Comment: @JMT_2080AD thanks, i'll learn about DOM ... BTW i learnt how to make the above code in R so i can edit what i want in this code throw R .

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thanks alot, now i've to find a way to put my code in a specific placemark at each minor folder

Comment: @hrbrmstr, i can't find a function that convert a nested list to xml , Please do u know something that can do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256064/how-to-create-xml-from-r-objects-e-g-is-there-a-listtoxml-function (is it really that difficult to search SO?)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, my list is a nested list, and i tried the last solution which has 2 ups, it was good but the problem is the output has something wrong, because it's repeat only one folder for so so many times. i can upload the output and let u see it

Comment: @hrbrmstr, could you check my second question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642725/how-to-convert-nested-list-to-xml-using-r
here's what the final result ... but i cant convert it to xml, 

xml <- listToXml(xml_data,tag = "All Maps")
you can see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found away but not so efficient, i open the kml file on NotePad++, then get the root and put it in xml file, then read the xml using this code,

```
Url <- "xml_data1.xml"
data <- xmlTreeParse(Url)
```

`xmlTreeParse()` allowed me to parse the xml file as a list, so i could add any thing to a specific place in the xml file, and this the code i used to add the node

```
data$doc$children$Folder[[3]][[3]][[3]][["description"]] <- top
```

be careful that there is difference between `XMLInternalElementNode` and `XMLNode`, so you can't use `saveXML()` directly like this ..

```
saveXML(data, file ="xml_data2.kml")
```

you should get the Root of data first

```
xmlroot <- xmlRoot(data)
saveXML(xmlroot, file ="xml_data2.xml")
```

this answer for writing the xml was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505906/use-r-to-read-a-xml-file-select-few-nodes-and-write-it-back-to-another-xml)

then you can open the xml_data2.xml using NotePad++ and get what you want then put it again into the kml file.