# How to convert nested list to xml Using R

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I've kml file and wanted to add nodes at specific place into it, so i wrote this code ..

```
library(XML)
kml.text <- readLines("C:/Users/pc/Downloads/Googletraffic/Maps/All Maps.kml")
xml_data <- xmlToList(kml.text)


top = newXMLNode("description")

table = newXMLNode("table ", attrs = c(width = 300, border = 1), parent = top)
tbody <- newXMLNode("tbody",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(All$TravelTime),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(All$TravelTime),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = table)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = max(All$TravelTime),parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)

th <- newXMLNode("img",attrs = c(src = URL,width = "700",height= "777",alt=""),parent =top )

top

description <- xmlToList(top)
xml_data$Document$Folder$Folder$Folder$Placemark$description <- description
```

that was the only way i found to add the html code to a specific position in the xml code, but when i convert "top" to "description" , the structure of data got changed and become useless,so is there any way to attached the html code to the xml_data without converting "top" to a list ?

and i got a function that convert nested list to xml, but the problem is that the code which writen in html will convert to xml and will not useful anymore.

```
root <- newXMLNode("root")
listToXML <- function(node, sublist){
    for(i in 1:length(sublist)){
        child <- newXMLNode(names(sublist)[i], parent=node);

        if (typeof(sublist[[i]]) == "list"){
            listToXML(child, sublist[[i]])
        }
        else{
            xmlValue(child) <- sublist[[i]]
        }
    } 
}
listToXML(root,xml_data)
```

this fuction written by Jeff Allen at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256064/how-to-create-xml-from-r-objects-e-g-is-there-a-listtoxml-function)

so, Please is there any way to attach this html code to the xml and when parsing the list to xml, the html code still html and not convert to xml ?

[here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2lPFjKRVKWWmdxc2dTcGpkdzQ) my kml file

Comment: I wrote the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623094/adding-a-tag-in-kml-file-using-r/39671366#39671366)) , Please check it .

Answer (score 3):

The `htmltools` package lets you build out nested nodes and you can use the `xmlParseString()` function to get your nodes:

```
library(htmltools)
library(magrittr)

tag("a", list(attr1="a1", attr2="a2", 
              tag("b", list(tag("c", list(attr1="c1", "C Content")), 
                            "B Content")), 
              "A Content"))  %>% 
  toString() %>% 
  xmlParseString() %>%
  str()
## Classes 'XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode' <externalptr>
```

Comment: thanks alot , but i made a node before, the problem now is to convert the nested list to xml

Comment: _that's what this does_. Remove the `xmlParseString()`. The whole thing makes a list turns it into XML and parses it into a node. You really need to try out things.

Comment: i'm spending hours trying codes to finish this work, i tried your code and tried it again on my data , here's what i tried 
x <- tag("a", xml_data)  %>% 
    toString() %>% 
    xmlParseString()
here's what i got 
Warning messages:
1: In if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored

Comment: you need to rebuild your list with `htmltools` tags or modify the `xmlToList` answer to handle the nesting.

Comment: root <- newXMLNode("root")
listToXML <- function(node, sublist){
    for(i in 1:length(sublist)){
        child <- newXMLNode(names(sublist)[i], parent=node);

        if (typeof(sublist[[i]]) == "list"){
            listToXML(child, sublist[[i]])
        }
        else{
            xmlValue(child) <- sublist[[i]]
        }
    } 
}
listToXML(root, xml_data)

Comment: this function is fairly good for converting my xml_data to a xml, but the problem now is that the html code which was "top" in my code above turns to xml and it become useless, is there any way to change all the xml_data except the html code ? i swear i'm spending 2days 24/7 working on this problem .... btw i'm not a programmer, so there are so manythings i don't know

Comment: i added node to xml file but i can't write it out, please if u can help, check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666820/inserting-a-node-to-a-certain-node-in-xml-file-using-r?noredirect=1#comment66637540_39666820