# inserting a node to a certain node in XML file Using R

Tags: r, xml

I've XML file, consist of 37 Major folder,each major folder has number of minor folders, and each minor folder has 3 placemarks.

i wanna add this node to the first placemark at this first minor folder which in the first major folder.

i tried to do that, but some problems faced me ...
first there's my node which i wanna add

```
top = newXMLNode("description")

table = newXMLNode("table", attrs = c(width = 300, border = 1), parent = top)
tbody <- newXMLNode("tbody",parent = table)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = tbody)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = 5,parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = tbody)

th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = 5,parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tr <- newXMLNode("tr",parent = tbody)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 =5,parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "MD",parent = tr)
th <- newXMLNode("th",attrs = c(scope = "col"),scope1 = "PM",parent = tr)
tbody <- newXMLNode("tbody",parent = table)

th <- newXMLNode("img",attrs = c(src = URL,width = "700",height= "777",alt=""),parent =top )
```

here's what i tried ...

```
data <- xmlTreeParse("xml_data.xml")
data$doc$children$Folder[[4]][[3]][[3]]$description <- top 
saveXML(data, file ="xml_data.xml")
```

first problem is : when i write "`data$doc$children$Folder[[4]][[3]][[3]]`" in console, the description node doesn't appear in the the console and when i write "`data$doc$children$Folder[[4]][[3]][[3]]$description`" it appears and i don't know why this happens..

2nd problem is : when i use `saveXML`to check if description is in the first place mark or not .... this error appears..

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLDocument"’
```

i searched for this and i found i should use `data <- xmlTreeParse(Url,useInternalNodes = TRUE )` .... but this doesn't allow me to use `data$doc$children$Folder[[4]][[3]][[3]]`...

so please, is there a way to add the node to this position in the xml file ? or is there a solution for my problems ?

[here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2lPFjKRVKWbHdBVWpkUmdjM28) my xml file .

Comment: You appear to want to embed an HTML table into XML file. Can you advise where in XML file as you are using numbered indices and not a element name path -`[[4]][[3]][[3]]` is not easily seen?

Comment: i used '[[4]][[3]][[3]]' ....  i use this formula because when i use $ after 'data$doc$children$Folder' i get only 3 options and there are 36 other option , so number 4 indicates to the first major folder,and [[3]] indicates to the first minor folder and [[3]] indicates for the first placemark

Comment: @Parfait, i found a way to add the html to the xml, but still stuck in problem that i can't save the xml into a file on my computer, could u please tell me if u know ? 

`data$doc$children$Folder[[4]][[3]][[3]][["description"]] <- top `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `getNodeSet` to find the specific element you intend to add the XML snippet, then in defining the new child make sure to reference the new element's parent to this nodeset:

```
data <- xmlTreeParse("xml_data.xml")
firstplacemark <- getNodeSet(data, "/Folder/Folder[1]/Folder[1]/Placemark")

top <- newXMLNode("description", parent = firstplacemark) 

#... same code as above 


saveXML(data, file="xml_data.xml")
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Folder>
  <name>All Maps</name>
  <visibility>0</visibility>
  <Folder>
    <name>Kornich ElNile</name>
     <visibility>0</visibility>
     <Folder>
       <name>Kornich ElNile;Zera3y To Arcadia</name>
       <visibility>0</visibility>
       <Placemark>
         <name>Directions from 30.10093 31.2401 to 30.07046 31.22686</name>
         <visibility>0</visibility>
         <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
         <LineString>
           <tessellate>1</tessellate>
           <coordinates>
                31.23924,30.09923,0 31.23904,30.09886,0
                31.23859,30.09802,0 31.23836,30.09758,0 31.23813,30.09719,0 
                31.23796000000001,30.09691,0 31.23781,30.09663,0 31.23747,30.09608,0 
                31.2371,30.09546,0 31.2351,30.09159,0 31.23495,30.09131,0 
                31.23487,30.09118,0 31.2347,30.09093,0 31.23448,30.09059,0 
                31.23437,30.09043,0 31.23428,30.09029,0 31.23422,30.09021,0 
                31.23415,30.0901,0 31.23406,30.08992,0 31.23397,30.08968,0 
                31.23387,30.08943,0 31.23373,30.08903,0 31.23359,30.08863,0 
                31.2335,30.08835,0 31.23344,30.08804,0 31.23338,30.08776,0 
                31.23332,30.08751,0 31.23321,30.08723,0 31.23313,30.08706,0 
                31.23306,30.0869,0 31.23295,30.08667,0 31.23293,30.08662,0 
                31.23281,30.08629,0 31.23273,30.08606,0 31.23272,30.086,0 
                31.23266,30.08576,0 31.23259,30.08551,0 31.23245,30.08498,0 
                31.23235,30.08466,0 31.23223,30.08428,0 31.23205,30.08388,0 
                31.23181,30.08342,0 31.23176,30.08333,0 31.23143,30.08276,0 
                31.23135,30.08261,0 31.23119,30.08228,0 31.23109,30.08202,0 
                31.23096,30.08167,0 31.2309,30.08148,0 31.23084,30.08124000000001,0 
                31.2308,30.08102,0 31.23078,30.08076,0 31.23077,30.08049000000001,0 
                31.23076,30.0803,0 31.23073,30.08011,0 31.23068,30.07991,0 
                31.23064,30.07979,0 31.23055,30.07957,0 31.23032,30.07908,0 
                31.23007,30.07857,0 31.23005,30.07854,0 31.22974,30.07796,0 
                31.22963,30.07776,0 31.22945,30.07743,0 31.22907,30.07672,0 
                31.22897,30.07651,0 31.22842,30.07561,0 31.22790000000001,30.07482,0 
                31.22782,30.07468,0 31.22758,30.07423,0 31.22754000000001,30.07415,0 
                31.22754000000001,30.07414,0 31.22751,30.07409,0 31.22744,30.0739,0 
                31.22738,30.07369,0 31.22735,30.07353,0 31.22735,30.07347,0 
                31.22731,30.07324,0 31.22729,30.073,0 31.22727,30.07256,0 
                31.22724,30.07227,0 31.22712,30.07166,0 31.22703,30.07125,0 
                31.22697000000001,30.07097,0                    
           </coordinates>
        </LineString>
        <description>
          <table width="300" border="1">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">5</th>
                <th scope="col">MD</th>
                <th scope="col">PM</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">5</th>
                <th scope="col">MD</th>
                <th scope="col">PM</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">5</th>
                <th scope="col">MD</th>
                <th scope="col">PM</th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody/>
          </table>
          <img src="http://www.example.com" width="700" height="777" alt=""/>
        </description>
      </Placemark>
 ...
```